# Swift 5.5: How to properly access the notification object inside the notification handler when its object has to be processed on the main queue?

Tags: swift, cocoa

This minimal example

```swift
class ViewController : NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSView.frameDidChangeNotification, object: view, queue: .main) { [self] n in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.resizeSubviews(animate: false, sender: n.object) // <- warning here
            }
        }
    }

    func resizeSubviews(animate: Bool, sender: Any?) {
    }
}
```

causes the warning:

```
Capture of 'n' with non-sendable type 'Notification' in a `@Sendable` closure
```

Although the Main dispatch queue is already asked for when adding the observer I have to wrap the `resizeSubviews` call in an `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.

How do I properly access n inside the notification handler?

Comment: Do you use the sender in resizeSubviews? You could just not pass it.

Comment: @jrturton Yes, I do. I need to know the sender of this message.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using, as I didn't get it on 14.3. Aside, wouldn't it be easier to override `viewWillLayout()`/`viewDidLayout()` and use constraints?

Comment: @Larme You can get that warning to appear if you change the "Strict Concurrency Checking" build setting to "Complete". You get the same issue even if you assign `n.object` to a local variable just before the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @Larme Yes, @HangarRash is correct. I am using Xcode 14.3.1 (14E300c). I have set "Strict Concurrency Checking"  to "Complete". Are you suggesting that there is no way to properly access `n` in this case? When this warning appears the design is wrong and it has to be changed?

Comment: Can't you use the object instead of the `Notification` inside the closure?

Comment: @Willeke When adding `let o = n.object` right before `DispatchQueue` and referencing `o` from inside the closure the warning changes to `Capture of 'o' with non-sendable type 'Any?' in a '@Sendable' closure`.

Comment: Swift doesn't like `Any?`, cast 'o' to something more specific.

Comment: @Willeke This! The solution is to capture the notification's object outside the async block and cast it to a specific type. It can then be accessed from within the async block. If you'd like to write that up as an answer I'll happily mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification is a non-sendable type, don't use it inside the closure. `n.object` is of type `Any?`, cast it to `NSView`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSView.frameDidChangeNotification, object: view, queue: .main) { [self] n in
    guard let sender = n.object as? NSView else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.resizeSubviews(animate: false, sender: sender)
    }
}
```